# about np.array convert size

Tags: python, numpy, svm

i use `np.array` to convert list,but size is not correct.
here is my code:

```py
    svm = create_SVM()
    samples = np.array(train_data, dtype=np.float32)
    response = np.array(labels, dtype=np.int32)
    if samples.size != response.size:
        raise ValueError(
            f'sample.size != response.size!\nsample.size:{samples.size} response.size:{response.size} train_data:{len(train_data)}')
    print('train start...')
    svm.train(samples, cv.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, response)
    svm.save("svm.yml")

// another function
        img = cv.imread(path.join(filename, file), 0)
        img = cv.resize(img, (64, 128))
        hog = cv.HOGDescriptor()
        hist = hog.compute(img)
        data = np.array(hist, dtype=np.float32).reshape(1, -1)[0]
        train_data.append(data)
        labels.append(label)
```

result is `ValueError: sample.size != response.size! sample.size:9552060 response.size:2527 train_data:2527`
why is `train_datasize` not equal to `sample`?

Comment: How can we possibly know that?  We don't know what `label` is.

Comment: `label` type is `int`. like 1 or 2 or ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing apples to oranges.  You're comparing `samples.size` to `len(train_data)`.  The numpy `size` property returns the total size of the array in all the dimensions.  The Python `len` function is only going to return the size of the first dimension.  I'm guessing `train_data` is a 2527 x 3780 array.  The `len` of that is 2527, the `x.size` is 9552060.

Comment: thx. and i got `SVM model data is invalid, check sv_count, var_* and class_count tags in function 'cv::ml::SVMImpl::write'`.could you help me?

Comment: No, please ask another question.  It seems like a pain, but you need to provide the new details.